# Convert the "floss" tag into a synonym to "open-source"

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

Browsing through our current tags, I see we have [open-source](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/open-source) (even with a tag wiki already), and [floss](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/floss) (which I just learned stands for "free/libre open-source software"). The latter IMHO is a rather uncommon (or at least less known; before yesterday, I only knew FOSS for "free and open-source") term for the same, as open-source generally is "libre" (you have the liberty to get the code and poke with it), and mostly free (except for donations).

**Request:** Shouldn't [floss](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/floss) be merged into [open-source](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/open-source), and then made a synonym to the latter?

I know there's a related discussion ongoing with [Tags for free software and free software?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/17/185). But AFAIR this "synonym" was something already agreed on (i.e. it was agreed both terms are *used* synonymously – not on the fact to create a synonym ;)

Comment: Yes, I agree. I'd never really heard FLOSS used before this site, and I had to Wikipedia it to find out. Open source, though, is much more widely known.

Comment: Wikipedia... didn't think of that. Ouch: *Somebody, please, shoot this pitiful acronym through the head and put it out of our misery* and *I continue to find it difficult to take seriously anyone who adopts an excruciatingly bad, haplessly obscure acronym associated with dental hygiene aids* – yes, I tend to agree :)

Comment: It would be nicer and fancier if we could get 
Robert Cartaino to synonymize them.

Comment: @Seth I would love to read his comment here, indeed :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Done!

*(expecting an email chiding me about some nuanced difference between them)*