# "Feature tags" only for required or also for optional features?

Tags: discussion, tags

Should "feature tags" (is there a better name?) like OS ([linux](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linux), [osx](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/osx), [windows](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows), …), license ([open-source](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/open-source)), and costs ([free](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/free)) only be used if they are **required** features?

Or may they also be used for **optional** features?

---

#### Example 1

The question [Desktop Publisher (Alternatives to InDesign)](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/525/60) is tagged with [free](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/free) and [open-source](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/open-source) (which would be valid combination, as Open-Source software must not be available for free). But in the question it says:

> Cost/Licence: Must be free, Ideally would be Open Source

So here [free](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/free) is required, while [open-source](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/open-source) is optional.

(Same case with the question [Free alternatives to Matlab that run on Linux?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/194/60).)

#### Example 2

The question [Free reference management software with full-text support](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/869/60) is tagged with [windows](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows) and [web-apps](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-apps). But in the question it says:

> Target environment: Windows desktop or web

So here not both must be true (web-apps running on a Windows server; or being available cross-platform), but only 1 of 2 is required.

#### Example 3

The question [Music manager for a mass storage based music player](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/571/60) is tagged with [windows](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows) and [linux](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linux). But in the question it says:

> I'm running Windows 7 and 8 mainly, so I would prefer windows, but I would accept a Linux based solution if nothing else is as good.

Here the software doesn’t have to be cross-platform, it’s either Linux or Windows (or both).

Comment: Related: [Can we agree on a tagging guide?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/467/60)

Comment: Related: [Function of tags](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/1146/60)

Answer (score 8):

Tags are not really for features. Features are usually too precise for a tag.

Tags on this site should be mainly about application domains or domains of expertise. For example, [windows](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows), [text-editors](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/text-editors), [math](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math), …

Tags like [free](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/free) are [still being debated](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17/tags-for-free-software-and-free-software), and definitely shouldn't be applied if the characteristic is optional — you shouldn't find non-free answers when you browse the [free](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/free) tag!

Comment: "Feature" is not the correct term, but as I explained in my question, I don’t know a better one. You used "characteristic", would this do? But more important than its name: Which are those tags (besides [tag:free])? Do you agree with the listing in the question: OS, license, cost? Some else? You mentioned [tag:windows] as "application domain" -- I’m not sure I understand it: Would you say [tag:windows] may also be used if the software is not required to run under Windows but the OP would prefer it?

Comment: (Making you aware that) I added two examples to the question.

Answer (score 7):

In my opinion, they should only be used for **required** features.

So in the example question, the tag [open-source](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/open-source) should be removed. The OP only requires that the software must be available for free, so users might answer with proprietary and with open-source software anyway. That the OP *prefers* open-source software can of course still be mentioned in the question text.

Otherwise, filtering by tag would lose much of its potential. When I filter for [open-source](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/open-source), I expect that *all* answers recommend open-source software, nothing else.

---

EDIT (new examples added to question):

For **example 2** and **example 3** it would mean that both of the OS/platform tags should be removed. So the OS requirements are only mentioned in the question/title, but not in the tags anymore.

When I’m filtering by [linux](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linux), I expect that *all* answers recommend software that runs on Linux.

Only use an OS tag if the recommended software MUST run on this platform.

Comment: I think you are right. I will remove the Open-source tag.

Comment: The implementation of this opinion requires that all operating systems tags be removed when the poster specifies that the software can run on one of multiple different operating systems (but does not need to run on all of them).  For example, sometimes posters say that the software can run on Windows or Linux, and therefore they add a tag for both operating systems.  Those tags will all need to removed if this opinion becomes policy.

Answer (score 2):

I think the tags should be used to requirements.

As you pointed out in the **first example**:

> Cost/Licence: Must be free, Ideally would be Open Source

the tag usage would be [free](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/free) and the [open-source](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/open-source) would be removed, because it's optional.

On the **second** and **third examples**:

the tags [windows](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows), [web-apps](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-apps) and [linux](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linux) would be removed. Because the requirement is not based on the system itself (but the software must run in a determinate system).

There should be created a tag with a name like [os-required](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/os-required) for the **second example** that shows that the OP wants a specific platform.

The tag [cross-platform](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cross-platform) doesn't fit any of the examples above. But it should be used when needed.