# Private beta cleanup: tag synonyms and tag merges

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms, tag-merge

This post is for all tag synonyms and tag merges so that we don't end up filling the front page of meta with synonym and merge requests.

## How to use this post

Post each requested tag synonym and tag merge as an answer below. Try to post one tag per answer, where "one tag" is one remaining tag *after* the merge/synonym has been actioned so that we can keep it nice, clean and obvious what is going on.

> **Post your answers as community wikis so that they can be maintained by anybody.**

Upvote and downvote each answer to show your agreement or disagreement with the proposal, post your thoughts in comments against each answer. Delete completed merges and synonyms from the answer list so that it's obvious what is still outstanding.

Comment: [More or less related](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/374/lets-tighten-the-reins-of-the-tags) could be a guide to find tags that needs some action.

Comment: Let's stop using this thread now that we're in public beta. If there are any outstanding tag issues that warrant discussion, start a separate thread.

Comment: This question is about tag cleanups during the private beta and has now outlived its usefulness. For new tag-related issues, [ask a new question](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=discussion+tags).

Answer (score 10):

> **DONE** (re-tagged by Braiam; synonym still needed)

We've got two tags for translation software:

- [translation](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation)
- [translators](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translators)

We only need one, so I would recommend merging and creating a synonym from one to the other. I personally think this should be translation > translators.

Comment: Done...........

Comment: @Braiam partially :) Not yet synonymized (noone of us has the required powers yet). Still: shall we rather let `translators` die silently? Otherwise we had to ping a CM for synonym creation (until we have a mod ourselves).

Answer (score 5):

> **DONE** (re-tagged; synonym needed?)

We've got [mail](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mail) and [emails](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emails). No difference to me, should be merged. Optionally synonymized. Merged.

Comment: Do we need a synonym here (mail → emails)? If not, I'd delete this answer to keep things clean here.

Comment: please, delete the answer if everything is doen.

Comment: I take the vote on the first comment with the comment of Braiam as "no synonym needed"? Two (or more) votes on this comment, and I delete the answer (the voter breaking this threshold please leave a comment to ping me).

Comment: I agree that [tag:mail] should be a synonym of [tag:emails]

Comment: Please, upvote the first comment if you feel a need for this synonym. Upvote the second comment if you think it's not needed (and I should simply delete my answer).

Answer (score 5):

We've got [mail](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mail), [emails](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emails) and [email-client](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/email-client). While the first two are already dealt with in my other request: [email-client](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/email-client) should either be merged into that other group as well, or we wait for [email-server](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/email-server). In the latter case, do we still need [emails](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emails), or rather stick to the two client/server tags? I could imagine [emails](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emails) used in other contexts as well, e.g. some management or maintenance software with the strong requirement to notify by mail. Opinions? I'm open to all ends :)

Comment: I think 'email' and 'email-client' should be synonyms. 'email-server', 'email-library' etc. are distinctive enough to not need an 'email' to it.

Comment: There are no such tags (email with either library or server). But of course, we could simply use `mail`+`server` to indicate a request on email-servers.

Comment: I prefer emails-client and email-server and ditch e/mail altogether.

Comment: @Izzy NOOOOOOOOOOO! [That is precisely what I said we shouldn't](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/374/lets-tighten-the-reins-of-the-tags). Then we will get "server" tags alone which will not tell us anything.

Comment: @Braiam Good point indeed! But would you prefer a few hundred `abc-server` and `abc-client` tags? I'm open to alternatives, of course!

Comment: @Izzy that is more sane. Also, there are a handful of servers-client programs.

Comment: @Braiam how many fingers do your hands have? Lemme count: mail, web, ftp, ssh, vnc, rdp, ical, samba, nfs, x-windows, sap, database, dns, time, ldap, application, streaming, dlna, internet-radio, ip-tv, sip, ... wow, you've got *really* large hands, I see... ;) But as I wrote, open for alternatives ;)

Comment: @Izzy I think you should focus on the protocols instead. Application is not a server-client stuff. I expect streaming covering internet-radio and ip-tv. There are other stuff like rpd/x-windows/vnc that goes into remote-desktop. Well, as you see I categorized them by usage

Comment: But how would you cover "application-server"? Agreed on the grouping (streaming, remote-desktop). Still leaves a lot, even when going "by protocol" (unless you want to group dns, time, sip & co as "tcp/ip" :)

Comment: [tag:email-client] = MUA, it's more specific than [tag:emails]. Keep both.

Comment: I need to remember phrasing my answers here in a way that makes it clear what up/downvotes stand for. Should I remove this one, and replace it with a more clear variant (including a summary of comments from here)?

Comment: @Izzy Leave it the way it is. Upvotes means "action needed" downvote means "No action needed" imo and thats quite clear. Also, as we currently only have "emails" and "email-client" and the amount of rep necessary to create new tags will go up soon I think this will even itself out.

Comment: Partially agreed, with one small adjustment: on Meta, upvotes mean agreement, and downvotes disagreement. So the question remains: What action should be taken here concerning `email-client`? I's not a clear "synonym".

Comment: Please: "email" not "emails".  Email is already a mass noun.

Comment: @IraBaxter you probably wanted to comment on [that answer](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/465/185)? This one here deals with "email-client" ;)

Comment: Do we need a `webmail` synonym here? See http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/660/are-questions-on-webmail-recommandations-acceptable?noredirect=1#comment1742_660 .

Answer (score 4):

> DONE retagging. Synonym needed.

Synonym [blueray](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blueray), [cd](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cd) and [dvd](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dvd) to [optical-media](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optical-media). All programs addressing one will most likely also address the other.

(Edit after two upvotes) Should also include [optical-drive](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optical-drive).

Comment: Not always, and I think [tag:dvd] is a bad tag as well, should probably synonym both of them to [tag:optical-media] or something that actually clearly covers both instances

Comment: @Flyk Agreed...

Comment: A *little* hesitating, thinking of questions like "Video editor that can export to blueray" (not just dvd). But OTOH, that's better defined in the topic of the question if it's that important. So +1 from me, too.

Comment: bluray is still optical media

Comment: I forced in synonyms [tag:dvd], [tag:cd-rom] (SO), [tag:compact-disc] (SU) and [tag:data-cd] (U&L). I'm not sure about Blu-ray which may still be new enough to warrant its own tag, we'll see when it comes up.

Answer (score 4):

> Synonym needed (mod required to do this :)

Synonym [chat](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chat) into [instant-messaging](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/instant-messaging). They cover the same aspects.

Answer (score 4):

[images](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/images) is a little confusing, and *maybe* should be renamed to [pictures](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pictures). Otherwise there might be confusion when it comes to graphics versus disk-images. Same could be said for [image-editing](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image-editing) (as one could edit e.g. an iso-image as well).

Sure, that could be made clear in the tag-wiki (and excerpt), as currently done by Angelo. But it might prove useful to have a separate tag for [disk-images](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/disk-images), thus when asking for them and starting to type "image", the correct tag pops up.

If agreed on that, we could simply check whether we have a corresponding question, and add that (not-yet-existing) tag to it – then editing the tag-wiki.

Comment: No images or pictures. Just narrow it down to some tags that has some proper meaning on their own.

Answer (score 4):

[virus-scanner](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/virus-scanner) should be merged and synonymized into [antivirus](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/antivirus).

Comment: Which one to keep which one to go?

Comment: I'd say to keep `antivirus` as master (tag), as that also implies the cleanup-task. `virus-scanner` is just one aspect of that; but as people might tend to use this, I'd recommend making it a synonym.

Comment: [so], [su], [ubuntu.se], [android.se] and [apple.se] all use either [tag:anti-virus] or [tag:antivirus].

Comment: @Gilles That's what I proposed as *target*. So "virus-scanner" should either become a *synonym* to "antivirus", or die with fire (after its questions have been merged into "antivirus" :)

Answer (score 3):

[multiplayer](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multiplayer) is a feature tag that will only be used in conjunction with [game](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game). I think this tag should be removed completely as it doesn't really add anything and this detail should be included in the question body as a requirement rather than as a tag.

Answer (score 3):

> **DONE** retagging. Synonym needs a mod.

Synonym [kids](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kids) into [children](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/children).

Comment: Retagged the single [kids] question to [children].

Answer (score 3):

> DONE retagging - Synonym needed.

Tags [log](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/log) and [log-analyzer](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/log-analyzer) should be merged and synonymized, making [log](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/log) final tag.

[SO](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/logging): [log](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/log), [logs](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logs) → [logging](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logging)
[SU](https://superuser.com/tags/logging): [log](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/log), [logs](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logs) → [logging](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logging)
[AU](https://askubuntu.com/tags/logging): [log](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/log), [logs](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logs) and [logging](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logging) exist
[U&L](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/logs): [logging](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logging) → [logs](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logs)
[Apple](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/logs): [logs](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logs)
[Android](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/logs): [logging](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logging)

Going for [logs](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logs) as the main tag.

Comment: Which direction? Would the final tag be [tag:log] or [tag:log-analyzer]?

Comment: [tag:log] should be final tag, Updated

Answer (score 2):

> For the mods: Please merge+synonymize, as we cannot do so :)

Synonym and merge [mms](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mms) and [sms](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sms) to [short-messaging](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/short-messaging). The distinction is too narrow and if one (but not the other) is needed it should be stated in the question.

Comment: Maybe we need a common denominator here. What about "short-messaging", and synonym "mms" *and* "sms" to it?

Comment: "mobile-messaging" would include things like WhatsApp, Skype, and even mails. Too ambiguous IMHO.

Comment: @Izzy Okay, I added both. Lets hope the "processing mod" doesn't mind doing the decision. I can live with [tag:short-messaging] just as good.

Comment: Just placed the "summary". Re-tagging alone makes no sense here: as long as it's not synonymized, the "empty tag" will be used sooner or later.

Comment: [tag:mms] is more specific than [tag:sms]. Nobody uses [tag:short-messaging]. I see nothing to be done here.

Comment: @Gilles don't you think mms is too narrow?

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer No, why? In any case, it doesn't hurt: the worst thing that can happen is that nobody uses it. Narrow tags are less of a problem than ambiguous tag.

Answer (score 2):

remove [resource-packing](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resource-packing). I think it is too narrow. Done.

Answer (score 2):

Remove [stack-exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stack-exchange). Too narrow for software.

Comment: Agreed. If needed, this should be part of the title (and/or the question itself).

Comment: In this instance, removing this tag would leave a question with just an operating system tag on it

Comment: @Flyk So be it. Maybe it can gain better tags. But this doesn't improve the quality of this tag.

Answer (score 2):

Synonym [standalone](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/standalone) into [desktop-client](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/desktop-client).

The single `standalone` question has been retagged, but I think this tag will come up again.

Comment: I've retagged the single [standalone] question to [desktop-client].

Answer (score 2):

Remove (and blacklist) [viewer](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/viewer). It should be stated more precise what kind of viewer is requested.

Comment: Agreed. Too broad.

Comment: I agree with blacklisting it as well

Answer (score 2):

Rename [vim-plugins](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vim-plugins) to [vim-plugin](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vim-plugin).

Answer (score 1):

[screen](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/screen) ([SO](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/screen), [Apple](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tags/screen)), [monitors](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monitors) ([U&L](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/monitors)) → [display](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/display) ([SU](https://superuser.com/tags/display), [AU](https://askubuntu.com/tags/display))

Comment: [tag:display] > [tag:screen] IMO. Screen is too close to [tag:screenshot] problematic.

Comment: @Fractaliste No. They are used incoherently. (`screen` is a unix command line tool, `display` can be virtual or physical. But `screen resolution` addresses that of a physical display. Also `display` is used synonym to `to show sth.`) YMMV but thats the point as there is no consistent separation of one to the other.

Comment: Retagged the single [display] question to [screen].

Comment: We should probably use [tag:display] as the main tag, to be compatible with [su].

Comment: @Gilles or be compatible to SO where there is no display tag (but a screen tag)

Answer (score 1):

> **DONE** retagging. Synonym needed.

synonym [osm](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/osm) to [openstreetmap](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/openstreetmap) as it is a common abbreviation.

Comment: OSM could be a completely different abbreviation. Just stick to the unabbreviated name. Generally speaking, don't use abbreviations in tag names.

Comment: @Gilles there are lots of abbreviation tags on SO. (java-ee, gcc, rdmbs, asp, ...) So, while I agree that the unabbreviated is better we should syn such common ones.

Comment: These aren't abbreviations, these are proper names (which happen to be built from the first letters of some words — or sometimes they're backronyms).

Comment: @Gilles GCC has over 40 possible meanings and that only on wikipedia. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gcc ASP has about 20. YES this is an abbreviation.

Comment: @Gilles Also "osm" is a synonym tag to "openstreetmap" even on SO so, I guess that counts as "proper name"

Answer (score 1):

[Definition of [cross-platform] tag](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/395/definition-of-cross-platform-tag) still unclear. See [cross-platform](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cross-platform).

Answer (score 1):

> **DONE** re-tagging. Do we really need a synonym here?

Remove [coffeescript](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coffeescript). Too narrow. [javascript](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/javascript) should be sufficient (and the former a synonym to the latter)

Comment: Not really a synonym. [CoffeeScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CoffeeScript) *is a programming language that transcompiles to JavaScript.* I agree to the re-tag nevertheless (too narrow). Not sure whether it requires a synonym, though.

Comment: I don't insist on the synonym. Just feels like it will reduce the number of future Qs we have to retag because of this.

Comment: OK, leaving that part as "open question" then. In case the "processing mod" makes a decision on it, so be it :)

Answer (score 0):

Synonym [graphics](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphics) into [images](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/images).

Specific kinds of graphics ([vector-graphics](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vector-graphics) etc.) already have their own tags that should be used instead of [graphics](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphics). If a game related question wants to address the visuals of it this should be noted in the question and not by tag.

---

Edit after two upvotes: Izzy raised concerns the [images](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/images) tag could be confused with disk-images, so maybe [pictures](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pictures) would be a better term here. However, this would cause inconsistencies when it comes to [image-editing](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image-editing) (unless we speak about disk-images here as well) etc.

Comment: Making the "emptied tag" at least a synonym then, this should be fine: images are graphics, and graphics can be said to be images (even graphs could, technically). How you call it rather depends on the "area of intention" (a graph or diagram I'd rather call a graphic than an image), so when starting to type the "wrong" tag-name, the "correct" one should appear ;) // Full ack on the "specialized tags" included :)

Comment: @Izzy Agreed on synonyms. Fixed it in the answer.

Comment: Additional comment from the recent review-queue: is `images` really the correct term? Shouldn't that be `pictures`, to not confuse it with disk-images?

Comment: @Izzy pictures would in deed be better.

Comment: See my other "answer" on that. Trouble with `pictures` is: would we want to rename `image-editing` to `picture-editing` then? This consequence makes no sense to me. Hence I suggested to pick a matching Q (if we have one), and simply adding a (new) `disk-images` tag to it.

Comment: @Izzy hmm... I'm uncertain on this.

Comment: Let's wait for more input then, I'm also a little "undecided". // PS: And I didn't suggest synonymizing, as you put it into the question – I was just rising concerns on possible confusion.

Comment: As this is undecided, please open a new thread.

Answer (score 0):

> DONE retagging - Synonym needed.

Rename [nlp](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nlp) to [language-processing](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language-processing) and add synonym.

Comment: optionally synonymize, so typing "nls" (ya know, "lazy programmers are the best") turns up the correct one? Otherwise we might soon end up with a duplicate tag. Alternatively, we could wait for exactly that, and *if* it happens we can still synonymize?

Comment: @Izzy synonym is okay. (Although I understood "nlp" as "neuro linguistic programming" and thought: WTF?)

Comment: I'm not proficient in this area. If it's not clear (and "nlp" is used for multiple things), this might need discussion. Oh, it does: There's also "Nonlinear programming" (see [Wilipedia on "NLP"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NLP)). So we need to decide where it should point to.

Comment: @Izzy I would say "Natural Language Processing" will have the most use in the domain of software.

Comment: The only [tag:nlp] question was deleted, but for future reference, *natural* has to be there. The abbreviation NLP is very often used in the field. The full name [tag:natural-language-processing] is too long for Stack Exchange tags. [so] calls it [tag:nlp]; [cs.se] calls it [tag:natural-lang-processing] (after much hesitation).

Comment: @Gilles Okay, so should we leave it with "nlp" in case it shows up again?

Comment: These tags don't exist anymore. There is no question to put them on.

Answer (score 0):

Remove [social-networks](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social-networks) for the same reasons there is no `os` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Rename (and synonymy) [ssd](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ssd) into [harddrive](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harddrive). Add [hdd](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hdd) as synonym to it as well so we have one tag to handle physical harddrives. If a specific one is necessary it can be stated better in the title.

Comment: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/297/ssd-monitoring-software-for-os-x isn't specifically about SSD, so it should be tagged [tag:hard-disk] or some such and not [tag:ssd]. But that doesn't make [tag:ssd] a bad tag.

Comment: @Gilles This question is exactly about SSD. What other (Software) question could there be that is more about "ssd" that causes this tag to be valid? (Example, please)

Comment: I don't have an example. It may be that an SSD-specific question will arise. Until then, we can live with [tag:hard-disk] (which would be the right tag for this question since nothing about it is specific to SSD).

Comment: @Gilles if it is sufficiently rare, we don't need a tag for it.

Comment: I left it alone, [tag:ssd] is only on one question. When it comes up, please use a hyphen between words in tag names: [tag:hard-disk] or [tag:hard-drive].

Answer (score 0):

> **DONE** re-tagging. Synonym needed?

Synonym [cloud-application](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cloud-application) to [cloud-service](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cloud-service)

Comment: I just retagged the only "cloud-application" question to "cloud-service"

Comment: So do we need a synonym here? Basically, a cloud-application is *using* a cloud-service, so they are *related* (not really synonyms). I tend to *not* make a synonym. If agreed, please remove this answer as "completed".

Comment: @Izzy Here I think a synonym is needed.

Comment: Marked it accordingly. Hopefully others leave opinions. I'm undecided on this (concerning "synonym needed").

Comment: No! [These mean different things](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/397/mysterious-cloud-tag/406#406).

Comment: @Gilles Okay. Would you write the tag-wiki to make that difference clear?

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer We're still arguing about cloud-XXX vs web-XXX in another thread.

Answer (score 0):

What about file format tags like [raw](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/raw), [mp3](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mp3), [csv](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/csv), [xml](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xml), [midi](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/midi) and [pdf](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pdf)? (those I found, but many other will be created when the beta'll be opened to the public...)

There are an infinite variety of file format, so I think they should be removed, except those which have an other meaning (like some programming language name like [php](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/php) which can help people to find a php tools, ...).

Comment: Removing alone does not help here, as they's re-appear as long as not blacklisted or turned into synonyms. Agreed that we shouldn't have a separate tag for each file format (too much clutter).

Comment: Having separate tags per file format makes perfect sense. Having to read or write a specific file format is an easy-to-search-for objective requirement.

Answer (score 0):

What is a [google-apps](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-apps)? Is it an [android](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android) app or an app working with GoogleDrive, Gmail, GoogleKeep, GoogleGlasses, ... ?

Comment: No idea, please open a separate thread.

Answer (score -1):

[REVOKED: See comments] (I can't delete it today as my quota is used up, I delete it tomorrow)

Rename [partition](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/partition) to [file-system](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/file-system). I think "partition" is too narrow for a tag.

Comment: Object. Think of people wanting to manipulate their disk partitioning (Partition Magic etc.). I wouldn't tag such a question `file-system`, feels wrong.

Comment: @Izzy So you think 'partition' is not too narrow? If you think it is too narrow but 'file-system' is no good for it - would you recommend an alternative?

Comment: I think the two are no synonyms. Feels a bit like putting "bottles" into "liquids", just because the latter ships in the former :)

Comment: @Izzy So you agree that 'partition' is too narrow and should be removed?

Comment: I didn't say either. I just said the two are no synonyms, and thus the renaming would be incorrect. What should happen with the `partition` tag, is something completely different.

Comment: Very well. Have a look: http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/423/private-beta-cleanup-tag-synonyms-and-tag-merges/508#508

Answer (score -1):

Remove [partition](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/partition) as it is too narrow. The part of the file system a questioner wants to address should be stated in the title.

Comment: A [partition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_partitioning) is no part of the [file system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system). On the contrary, a file system *can* be part of a partition (unless the latter is used as [raw device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raw_device)).

Comment: [tag:partition] should perhaps be [tag:disk-partition] to put it in context, but it's different from filesystem, with not all that much overlap.

Comment: @Gilles thats the other suggestion. This one just says: Kill it.

Answer (score -1):

[distribution](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/distribution) is ambiguous. Currently used for "Linux distributions", it could also refer to any other kind of software distribution (repositories, downloads, web documents, whatever) – even to shipment of other wares.

I suggest we keep it as-is, but make that clear in the tag-wiki. Who agrees, please upvote – who disagrees, please downvote this answer :)

**EDIT:** To make it clear, please "upvote" to keep or "downvote" to delete this tag. Though in 80%+ used in the meaning "Linux distro", I don't feel it's *strongly required*.

Comment: remove distribution.

Comment: The tag – or my answer? If the former: should it be "renamed", or simply removed altogether?

Comment: The tag. It should be removed. [tag:linux] says it all.

Comment: Not sure if the "linux" tag alone says the search is for a distribution. The "linux" tag IMHO stands for software that *runs* on linux. If a question is tagged "windows", it's unlikely the questioner wants to know whether to use Vista or Win8 :)

Comment: I think that both uses fit nicely into [tag:linux]. Even more so as there is no equivalent in other OSes. Nobody would tag a "Which Windows Version to use" as [tag:distribution].

Comment: Exactly. But a tool to distribute files might be tempting. Or one to distribute some other information in special ways. That's why I wrote "ambiguous". "To distribute" means as much as "to spread", "to share" (don't say "too broad" now :)

Comment: You have convinced me. Too broad. Its unclear. Cleanse it WITH FIRE.

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer *Yuck* that back-fired. The word "distribution" is (in our context) in 80%+ applied meaning "Linux distro". My intention hence was not to remove it, but make it clear in the tag wiki (if we all agree to use it that way). But of course I'm open for "cleansing" as well, as I don't feel it's really *strongly* required. But I'd like some more people voting that first (downvote for delete, upvote for keep).