# Too narrow tags: What to do with them?

Tags: discussion, tags

We've got a bunch of tags which are pretty narrow, and thus not much of use. Similar to [Private beta cleanup: tag synonyms and tag merges](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/423/185), I suggest we use this "question" to collect those CW-wise to decide on each one (one tag per answer).

Other than "over there", answers here should not be deleted, but "marked with the solution" (preferably edited into the *top* of the answer) for later reference – just in case the very same tag pops up again later.

Answer (score 5):

> **REMOVED** Only 1 question used it, in the sense of "collaboration" → re-tagged.

[change-history](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/change-history): quite narrow. True, useful for many development (and other) stuff – but does it really need a specific tag? I'd say: No, and we remove it.

Answer (score 5):

> **REMOVED** Only 1 question used it, removed the tag from it as "being meta"

[bootable](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bootable) is a little strange. If the question is for a specific OS: that's bootable by definition. Other software is not "bootable" at all.

**Explanation:** Behind that stands a misunderstanding, at least in most cases. People think e.g. of "stand-alone virus-scanners", where you put the CD/USB-Stick in, and it starts automatically with the scan process. But that's rather a Live-CD (or stick). It's not the application booting up, but the underlying OS, which then automatically starts the AV-software. Like via an `autoexec.bat` (DOS/Windows) or some init script (*nix).

**Conclusion:** The tag makes no sense – unless interpreted as "common parent" to Live-CDs/DVDs/Sticks, in which case it's at least "confusing". At the moment, I cannot think of another "common term" to better match this.

Suggestions please in the comments :)

Comment: Remove it. . . . .

Answer (score 3):

> **REMOVED** from the only question using it.

[code-coverage](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-coverage) is much to specific, and should either be merged (and optionally synonymized) into [code-review](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-review) or deleted altogether.

Comment: If a tag is already covered by another... why create it?

Comment: @Braiam This tags are already in use. What to do with them?

Comment: Remove it......

Comment: I agree with @Braiam here (remove `code-coverage`), and don't think a merge+synonym makes sense here. The only question holding it currently could simply be re-tagged.

Comment: I don't see what's wrong about [tag:code-coverage]. It has a clear meaning, and is the natural term to use for tools that measure code coverage. Why do you consider it “much too specific”?

Comment: Isn't it just one of the aspects to code-review or unit-test? IMHO rather something that belongs to the description. I might be wrong, though, not being a "real dev" :)

Answer (score 2):

[parallel](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parallel): only used on one [question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1197/document-scanning-software-with-ocr-that-takes-advantage-of-multiple-cpus), in combination with [multi-core](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multi-core) which is basically the same but better worded IMO. **Removed** from the question; so it will be trashed when SO next refreshes the tags list. *Speak out if you disagree*.

Comment: [tag:parallel] isn't the same as [tag:multi-core]: it also covers distributed parallel processing.

Comment: Yes but how many questions will there be to specifically require that? I think it is insufficient... calling other views

Comment: On [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parallel), the `parallel` tag is partly about GNU Parallel and partly about parallel processing in general. In the part about parallel processing in general, not all questions are about sharing CPU resources.

Answer (score 2):

[partition](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/partition) is too narrow. That is just one aspect of HDD oriented tools and should be stated in the Questions text, not in a Tag.

Comment: Not sure whether to count that "too narrow". It's a question not only for HDDs on computers, but also something coming up for SDCards on mobiles (on Android, we get this when it comes to "moving apps" with App2SD+ or Link2SD, or (not that frequent anymore) "using swap"). Also, re-partitioning without data loss is a not that uncommon question. *Maybe* "partitioning" would be the better tag-term here, though.

Comment: I'd say [tag:partition] is too ambiguous, but definitely not too narrow. Rename to [tag:disk-partitioning]?

Answer (score 1):

[amazon](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amazon): do we really need such a specific tag? I could imagine a more common [shopping](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shopping) or something similar. Please, put your ideas in the comments to this answer.

**EDIT:** (just for clarification) "Upvote" for "kill", "Downvote" for "keep".

Comment: I don't see a single situation where either amazon or "shopping" alone will be useful.

Comment: I think its on the border of 'too narrow'. But on the "keeping" side. Amazon has various APIs and there are tools to interact with them. Maybe expand the tag-wiki to include "everything thats to do with all the amazon services" so we don't get all the "amazon" tags SO has.

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer So you see a lot of requests coming in for that tag, or a wide range of SR it would be useful to? I rather tend to agree to Braiam, but that might be due to "lack of information".

Comment: @Izzy If you look at the amount of questions there are on SO for all the `amazon` tags I would bet there will come people to us.

Comment: OK then. Waiting for a few notes from others, before I edit my answer to "KEEP" :)

Comment: Due to AWS (Amazon Web Services) APIs and that lot I'd say keep

Comment: No, don't keep. Not specific enough. What would a software recommendation question have to do with amazon? Except EC2, which should have its own tag. If I need to use an Amazon API that info should be in the question, not the tags.

Comment: [tag:amazon] is far too ambiguous, there should be separate tags for the shopping site and the various hosting platforms (AWS, EC2, …).

Comment: @Gilles so remove? Votes currently are "neutralized" (did you put yours?).