# Should there be a tag for "pay once" software?

Tags: discussion, tags

There has been [a recent question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/17327/6834) where the OP later specified in the comments that he's open to paid software as long as he pays once for a lifetime.

Even the Apple's App Store now has a chart for "Pay Once & Play" apps. Source: [Apple has a new section in the App Store to highlight games that don't make you keep paying to play](http://uk.businessinsider.com/apples-pay-once-and-play-section-of-the-app-store-highlights-games-without-in-app-purchases-2015-2?op=1?r=US)

I feel that this is a common enough case to deserve a tag. What do you guys think?

---

My suggestions for this tag are [single-payment](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-payment) or [single-transaction](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-transaction)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Though I see your point, I doubt that will be a useful tag. If a user wishes that approach, it should be pointed out with the question itself.

Currently, we don't even have any tag specifying "payed". People who'd accept to pay for software certainly wouldn't reject the very same tools just because they're available for free – so we have the [gratis](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gratis) tag for people not willing to pay at all. Just because something like "one-time pay, always play" exists doesn't mean we need a tag for that. A sentence like "I'm willing to pay at max [budget] one-time, but am not interested in re-occuring subscription fees" should suffice. We neither put tags for `max-USD50` or `low-cost` to limit payment, but say to include the budget with the question text ;)

Comment: I agree with the most part `People who'd accept to pay for software certainly wouldn't reject the very same tools just because they're available for free – so we have the gratis tag for people not willing to pay at all` But people who are not willing to pay more than once can't use the gratis tag, and yet at the same time they would reject a large part of paid software for being a subscription. It's not exactly a budget but more of a personal preference. I agree that it should be pointed out in the question, but a tag might also bring the asker's attention to that

Comment: IMHO "drawing attention" is not the purpose of tags (I've just checked our help-center for a definition, but couldn't find any). As Meta in this case is intended to find a consensus: Why don't you simply downvote my answer, and post an opposite one with exactly the reasoning from your comment? Sure I'm likely to downvote that then – but others can indicate their opinions voting up/down as well, and in a couple of days we should see a tendency (for those who don't know: that's what votes for here at Meta – not *rating the content*, but declare your opinion).

Comment: I think the main purpose of tags is to narrow down the answers and subgroup questions to facilitate searching. I'm not opposed to your answer, just not convinced yet. I agree that it's a better idea to leave it for voting

Comment: Same with me, Timmy: As written, I see your point – and I also share the idea of tags for searching. I'm open to both variants, though I'm currently tending to what I wrote in my answer. Like you, I'm not "absolutely opposed" but neither convinced – so let the feet decide (voting). Maybe we'll also have some "enlighning comments" to finally convince us one way or the other :)

Comment: @Izzy I added an answer that could convince you.

Comment: I've actually read it before seeing your comment :) While I can better warm to `pay-once` than to one of the other two, my opinion stays "neutral". Will we need a tag to indicate subscription-based payment as well? I already see questions carrying all 3 tags then...

Comment: @Izzy if someone comes up with that and cares for the concept, then yes. I don't think it will come up as I can't think of somebody who prefers paying regularly, but the world continues to amaze me with the people in it and the variety of their opinions.

Answer (score 2):

A [single-transaction](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-transaction) tag could serve to indicate that the asker is only interested in softwares that do not require regular or additional payments after downloading. It would represent a superset of the [gratis](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gratis) tag along with "Pay once" software.

Comment: If that gets used add "pay-once" as a synonym, please.

Comment: Nobody would look for `single-transaction` or associate that with payment *unless being explicitly told* it's supposed to be connected. Just seeing the tag I'd rather connect it with databases. And no, most people don't read tag excerpts, let alone tag wikis. If we'd create such a tag at all, it must be easily identified – so it should rather be `pay-once`, as even `single-payment` is ambiguous.

Comment: @Izzy I agree. `pay-once` is more intuitive. I'm voting for Angelo's answer

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr: Use [pay-once](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pay-once).

Lets see if the tag [single-transaction](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-transaction) has merit by the guidelines of [the help center](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/tagging), in particular in comparison to [gratis](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gratis).

1. Describes the topic of the question: **Good**. As much as gratis does.
2. Connecting experts with questions: **Good**. A little less then gratis, but still.
3. Mark questions that are relevant to you: **Good**. You do care about that concept.
4. One should avoid creating new tags if possible: **Good** I don't think this information is not well searchable without that tag.
5. When naming a tag, think about how someone would search for that subject. **Bad**. People would search for [pay-once](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pay-once). Maybe a synonym can clear that out. But [gratis](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gratis) has the same problem.
6. Works as the only tag on the question: **Bad** But, so is [gratis](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gratis).
7. No subjective tags: **Good**. The function is clear and unambiguous.

Score: 5/7 - same as [gratis](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gratis). I think it will find much less use but "too narrow" is not a problem for a tag. I say just add [pay-once](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pay-once) on a bunch of questions that match it and see how they fare.

Comment: I agree with `pay-once`. Thanks for the explanation. I'm convinced by it, but will give it some time to see how the votes turn out

Answer (score 1):

Assuming we would have such a tag, I think it would certainly be [one of those tags](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/271/60) that should only be used if it’s a [*required*](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/272/60) restriction.

So for a question tagged with [pay-once](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pay-once) (or [single-transaction](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-transaction), or similar), answers **should not recommend gratis software**.

This is probably not what OPs would want/mean. To circumvent this problem, the tag would have to be named [gratis-or-pay-once](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gratis-or-pay-once) or so. Ugh.

(I think we don’t need such a tag at all, so I agree with [Izzy’s answer](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1082/60).)

Comment: My initial thought was that `single-transaction` also encompasses the `gratis` tag since it's basically still a single transaction of 0 units of currency at the time of the download. Right now the scale is tipping towards no tag, which is fair enough as long as the requirements are clear in the body of the question.