# Guide users who try to use the tag [free]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

I suggest we make a new tag [free](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/free) and then make it a synonym of [gratis](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gratis).

This will mean when new users type 'free', they are suggested with 'gratis'.

What do you think?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We [got rid of the tag `free` because it is ambiguous](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17/tags-for-free-software-and-free-software): it could mean [free (libre) software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) (i.e. open source, software that you can adopt and modify), or [freeware](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freeware) (gratis software, i.e. software that the vendor doesn't charge for).

It has recently become possible to show a short guidance text when a poster tries to use a blacklisted tag. I propose:

> The tag 'free' is ambiguous. Please use [gratis](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gratis) for software that doesn't require paying money, or [open-source](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/open-source) for libre/open-source software.

Comment: If that is possible, then yes, showing that note is perfect! So do mods do that? Or developers?

Comment: @ṧнʊß It's a developer-only feature. Let's give people a few days to discuss the wording, then one of us mods will contact the developers.

Comment: 4 votes now... :)

Comment: Although I realize that this "ambiguity" has been promulgated by open source advocates, I don't really think it is ambiguous in a practical sense.  When someone who has never heard of this issue asks for something free, they mean that they don't want to pay for it.  If they specifically know and mean they want it without intellectual property restrictions, they'll ask for "open source", "open", etc.

Comment: Agreed BrenBarn.